# Checking uniform continuity of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I need to check whether the function $f : (0,1) \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $f(x)= \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on its domain.

I know it is continuous since it is a composition of continuous functions. But I have no idea whether it is uniformly continuously or not. I am confused as to how one speculates about whether it will be or not by just looking at it.

I assumed that it is and I tried to estimate $|f(x)-f(y)|$ where $x$ and $y$ are in the domain but I can't proceed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm slowly learning MathJax. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can extend $f$ to $[0,1]$ in such a way that the extension is continuous you are done, since continuos functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. The extension to $x=1$ is obvious. Can you see how to extend it t0 $x=0$?

Comment: Oh yes! I know this theorem. I need to find limit of the function as x tends to 0, but I cant find a way to evaluate it. Any hint please? :)

Comment: $$e^{1/x}=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}+\dots>\frac{1}{2x^2}.$$ Then $$0<\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}=\frac{1}{x\,e^{1/x}}<2\,x.$$

Comment: With due respect, Sir, I don't get how this aids to finding extension at 0. Could you please explain? :)

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{-1/x}}{x}$?

Comment: 0. I got it. You squeezed the function. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You mean $\lim\limits_{x\to0^{\color{Red}+}}$. @Shubham

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, of course. But since $f$ was defined on $(0,1]$, that was the only possibility.

Comment: Writing $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ is fine, since $f$ is only defined on $(0,1]$. But $\frac{e^{-1/x}}x$ is defined on $\Bbb R\setminus0$, so you should use $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ there. I guess I'm just being pedantic.